# Function not working when using $( document ).ready on external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple button that calls a function inside `index.html`, and the function itself is in `script.js`, the function works when not using `$( document ).ready(function() { //...});` but as soon as I add this line (at `script.js`), it won't work. This is how it looks:

**index.html**:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

**script.js** with `$( document ).ready`: (**Not working**)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function myFunction(){
        alert("Alright!");
    }
});
```

**script.js** without `$( document ).ready`: (**Working**)

```
function myFunction(){
    alert("Alright!");
}
```

Comment: Have you add jquery to your proyect?

Comment: That's because in the first version you are only defining `myFunction` within the scope of the ready handler function.  So it's not available outside that scope.  Why are you even trying to do that?  The second version works, so what's the problem?

Comment: If you are going to use a document ready and declare methods inside it, bind event handlers dynamically, not inline.

Comment: I just needed it in a separate file, so I assume that if it's outside of the scope, it makes no sense to actually check documet.ready on an external file? Then, what would be the correct way to include document ready and, as you said - how to bind event handlers for my simple example above?

Comment: Thats one reason you should not use inline event liensteners `onclick="myFunction()"`. You instead should e.g. use `addEventListener('click', myFunction, false)` on the `button` element, or `$('button').on('click', myFunction)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery solves this problem using selectors and binding events

In this cas use `$('button').click();` to listen when the button is clicked.
Remove inline `onclick`

Hope this helps :>

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').click( () => alert("Alright!"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to add a library of JavaScript called jQuery. Because you are using the syntax of jQuery. (A rich and powerful JavaScript Library)

in Vanilla JavaScript we use `document.getElementById('btnSubmit')`
But in jQuery we write `$('#btnSubmit')` to do the same thing.

That's why you need to use the jQuery Library. You can use it directly form cdn or you can download it offline.

If you want to use cdn just add this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/core.js"></script>
```

One more thing in jQuery we use

`$(document).ready(function(){
//your code goes here
})`

to make sure that the Script will be effective after the DOM parsing/rendering is completed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that u can create a variable outside of the document.ready scope. Probably, not your best option, but will get job done.

```
var func;                      
$(document).ready(function(){
  func= function()
  {
    alert('Alright!');
  }
});



<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
```

Comment: This would work, but is a bad solution. You should not pollute the global namespace, and you should not use inline event listeners.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Dirty way to make things work

Answer (score 0):

The scope  of the anonymous function in`$( document ).ready()` no longer available when the execution of the function is finished . So can't call the function from this scope.

Answer (score -1):

That happen because when the HTML is loaded onClick attribute is readed but this function is still not loaded.

The best approach in this case is make the binding on ready event.